# Trying to get Average of Response Rates in Domo dashboard

Tags: sql, powerbi, visualization, dashboard, domo

I have a dashboard in Domo that is visualizing responses from different surveys.

I have a pivot table that creates a variable "Response Rate" and it just takes the sum of respondents who answered the question divided by total respondents who took the survey.

I would like to create a gauge that shows the average Response Rate, but instead of taking the Response Rate per survey and averaging them, it's taking the total (sum of people who answered the question across all surveys) / (total number of participants for all surveys).

So the 0.01 Response Rate is taking the 7,540 / 39 when I want it to average the Response Rate column.

Table photo:

[image: Table photo]

Response Rate variable formula:

[image: Response Rate variable formula]